# Simple spider with BS4 mysteriously doubles every page

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

So I've written a really simple one-level-deep spider with BS4.  The target is those obnoxious html-books-online formats (like in documentation) where there's a table of contents page, and then all the content is on pages linked from the main ToC page.  Assumes all content is vanilla html.  The goal is to save that kind of thing for offline reading.  And so the technique is to simply create a list of unique links off the main page, grab the content off each of the links, and concatenate the whole thing into one big html page, which can then be read offline at leisure.

And it works perfectly except for one tiny little maddening bug: in the ultimate html file, **every sub-page appears twice**.  Exactly twice. I've been testing it on this bash scripting tutorial http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/ (which I don't own the rights to, btw, though the copyright terms permit copying, so please don't test this on anything that slams the server or is otherwise impolite).

What I've checked:

- I've verified that the underlying pages don't themselves contain duplicate content hidden away in there.
- I've verified that `uniques` does in fact contain a list of unique links.
- I've verified that `len(texts) == len(uniques) + 1` as expected.

This is really starting to stump me now. This might be some kind of obvious stupid bug, but I can't see it at all and am going insane.  Can anyone see what's going wrong here?  Thanks!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import urllib 

def clearJunk(BSobj):
    [s.extract() for s in BSobj(['style', 'script'])]

def makeSoup(url):
    r = urllib.urlopen(url)
    soup = BS(r)
    clearJunk(soup)
    return soup

def getBody(BSobj):
    return ' '.join([str(i) for i in BSobj.find('body').findChildren()])

def stripAnchor(url):
    badness = url.find('#')
    if badness != -1:
        return url[:badness]
    return url

url = raw_input('URL to crawl: ')
soup = makeSoup(url)

links = filter(lambda x: 'mailto:' not in x, [url + stripAnchor(alink['href']) for alink in soup.find_all('a', href=True)])
uniques = [s for (i,s) in enumerate(links) if s not in links[0:i]]

texts = [getBody(makeSoup(aurl)) for aurl in uniques]
texts.insert(0, getBody(soup))
from time import gmtime, strftime
filename = 'scrape' + str(strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S", gmtime())) + '.html'
with open(filename, 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write('<br><br>'.join(texts))

print 'scraping complete!'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the way you find the children of the `body` tag in `getBody()`. By default, it works in a *recursive way*, sample:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<body>
    <div>
        <b>test1</b>
    </div>
    <div>
        <b>test2</b>
    </div>
</body>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
for item in soup.find('body').findChildren():
    print(item)
```

It would print:

```
<div>
<b>test1</b>
</div>
<b>test1</b>
<div>
<b>test2</b>
</div>
<b>test2</b>
```

See `test` and `test2` are repeated.

I think you meant to use `find_all()` with [`recursive=False`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-recursive-argument):

```
' '.join([str(i) for i in BSobj.find('body').find_all(recursive=False)])
```

This is what it would output for the sample HTML provided above:

```
>>> for item in soup.find('body').find_all(recursive=False):
...     print(item)
... 
<div>
<b>test1</b>
</div>
<div>
<b>test2</b>
</div>
```

Comment: Ooooh!  I think that is probably right.  Because the repetition does, on closer examination, appear to be of elements in pages rather than of whole pages.  Thank you!

Comment: Hmm.  I notice from the docs that the recursive flag only works with find and find_all, not find_children---but I think I need find_children to avoid including the body tag from each document.  That's an issue... I suppose I could strip it with regex and risk the wrath of Cthulhu...

Comment: @PaulGowder I think you need to use `find_all()`, `body` would not be included since you call `find_all()` on it..`BSobj.find('body').find_all(recursive=False)`..

Comment: Awesome!  Just tested. That worked like a charm.  Clearly I need to come to a better understanding of the beautifulsoup document model.  Thank you.